# How to find sum value of single column from multiple selected columns of stored procedure in sql

Tags: winforms, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

in my sql stored procedure i am selecting more column and i want to find the sum of the value of column NetAmount. only need to find sum of this column.
and also the other selected column value. how to select this.?

for this i put the code like this [compute sum(gensal.NetAmount)],this is working but not possible to select this value to my windows application through Entity framework.

this is a search query with optional parameter
@EmpId, @MonthId,@YearId

my code is:-

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SearchSalaryReport]

    @EmpId int=null,
    @MonthId int=null,
    @YearId int=null
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT ed.Name,
            desig.Designation,
            mon.Month,
            gensal.Year,
            gensal.BasicPay,
            gensal.CasualWorkedDays,
            gensal.CasualWorkedAmount,
            gensal.ApsentDays,
            gensal.ApsentDaysAmount,
            gensal.NetAmount

            --SUM(gensal.NetAmount)[sum] 

            from dbo.Tbl_GenerateSalary gensal join
            dbo.Tbl_Designation desig on gensal.DesignationId=desig.RecordId join 
            dbo.Tbl_EmployeeDetails ed on gensal.EmpId=ed.RecordId join
            dbo.Tbl_Month mon on gensal.Month=mon.RecordId
            where(isnull(@EmpId,0)=0 or gensal.recordId=@EmpId)
            and(ISNULL(@MonthId,0)=0 or gensal.Month = @MonthId)
            and(ISNULL(@YearId,0)=0) or gensal.Year = @YearId
            compute sum(gensal.NetAmount)



END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a case where it is rather obvious that the very common way to use SPs only to fetch data is not a good idea... It is extreme pain to continue with the return set of a SP.

Btw: Do not use the "SP_" prefix...

Try it with an inline function (or maybe with a VIEW):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetSalaryReport]
(
    @EmpId int=null,
    @MonthId int=null,
    @YearId int=null
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
    SELECT  ed.Name,
            desig.Designation,
            mon.Month,
            gensal.Year,
            gensal.BasicPay,
            gensal.CasualWorkedDays,
            gensal.CasualWorkedAmount,
            gensal.ApsentDays,
            gensal.ApsentDaysAmount,
            gensal.NetAmount

            from dbo.Tbl_GenerateSalary gensal join
            dbo.Tbl_Designation desig on gensal.DesignationId=desig.RecordId join 
            dbo.Tbl_EmployeeDetails ed on gensal.EmpId=ed.RecordId join
            dbo.Tbl_Month mon on gensal.Month=mon.RecordId
            where(isnull(@EmpId,0)=0 or gensal.recordId=@EmpId)
            and(ISNULL(@MonthId,0)=0 or gensal.Month = @MonthId)
            and(ISNULL(@YearId,0)=0) or gensal.Year = @YearId;
```

You can call this like any table, using all aggregate functions you want:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.GetSalaryReport(NULL,NULL,NULL);
SELECT SUM(NetAmount) FROM dbo.GetSalaryReport(NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

You can even use it in joins or with APPLY.

EDIT: If you want/have to keep your SP it is good practice to wrap the inline function. This will not change the behaviour of your application at all:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SearchSalaryReport]

    @EmpId int=null,
    @MonthId int=null,
    @YearId int=null
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT *
       --You could add your aggregate here, something like this
      --,(SELECT SUM(NetAmount) FROM dbo.GetSalaryReport(@EmpID,@MonthID,@YearID)) SumOfNetAmount
FROM dbo.GetSalaryReport(@EmpID,@MonthID,@YearID);
END
```

Comment: Sir, your above code is working fine, but when i connect it with winform application via entity framework i can't able to get the sum value..

Comment: @SalamIndianoor, what did you try? Calling the SELECT SUM () is a scalar call.

Comment: i tried like this---  select *from dbo.GetSalaryReport(@EmpId,@MonthId,@YearId)
   SELECT SUM(NetAmount) FROM dbo.GetSalaryReport(@EmpID,@MonthID,@YearID)  any probem..? this is getting the sum value in sql without colum name but not getting in c# because there is not column name to specify NetAmount

Comment: @SalamIndianoor, Are you aware of the fact, that the SUM is a scalar aggregate value? In general you should not mix a resultset with aggregations. Your SUM value will be part of each row, don't know if you want this. In my answer you find right at the end the call you could use to get all rows together with the SUM (called SumOfNetAmount), just take the second comment away. Your given code runs two separate queries... If you want a column name, you must use `SELECT SUM(NetAmount) AS YourColumnName FROM...`

Comment: @SalamIndianoor, one more hint: Probably it would be best to load the query without a SUM and calculate your SUM within your application's code.